# getting dynamic timezone offset based on month

Tags: postgresql

I've a query

```
"TO_CHAR((TIMEZONE('#{ tz_offset }', created_at) + (#{ months.to_s } * INTERVAL '1 month')))"
```

The final query becomes:

```
"SELECT sum(price) as sum_total, min(TO_CHAR((TIMEZONE('-05:00', created_at) + (0 * INTERVAL '1 month')), 'YYYY-MM')) as formatted_date, min(TO_CHAR((TIMEZONE('-05:00', created_at) + (0 * INTERVAL '1 month')), 'Mon/YY')) as key FROM items WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2018-09-01 04:00:00' AND '2020-02-01 03:59:59' GROUP BY TO_CHAR((TIMEZONE('-05:00', created_at) + (0 * INTERVAL '1 month')), 'YYYY-MM') ORDER BY TO_CHAR((TIMEZONE('-05:00', created_at) + (0 * INTERVAL '1 month')), 'YYYY-MM')"
```

As you can see the tz_offset becomes **-05:00**

However, the problem I'm running into is that the tz_offset is static, and it can change based on the month.  Such as, CST time is -05:00 in July but -06:00 in August.  I would like to make sure the amounts fall into correct months based on daylight savings.  Is it possible for postgres to calculate this tz_offset based on timezone?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using

```
created_at AT TIME ZONE <tz_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the offset, use the name of the time zone, for example `America/Chicago`. That includes the daylight savings time setting.